# ERC1155 return correct uri

Tags: erc-1155

I'm having erc1155 smart contract which is using following base url: `https://token-cdn-domain/{id}.json`. When i try to get the uri for token with id 5 for example i receive this: `https://token-cdn-domain/5.json` but in ipfs they are stored with leading zero padded to 64 hex characters length and `5` looks like this `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005.json` any idea how to provide the correct uri?

Comment: Are you asking how to format the `5` in solidity or in js?